# Displaying all the variables declared in a sh file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debugging

I have a test.sh file which contains something like the following

```
source lib.sh

input=$0

A=aa/bb/cc
B=$A/dd
C=$A/ee

doSomething $B $C
```

Is it possible to display the values of all the variables so that when I read the code, I don't have to trace their final value row by row.

In my case, I mean to display

```
input=$0 
A=aa/bb/cc
B=aa/bb/cc/dd
C=aa/bb/cc/ee
```

I know

```
bash -x test.sh
```

can achieve this goal; but I don't want test.sh to be executed. ( Executing the functions in test.sh would delete some important files on my disk.) I only want to know the values of all the variables.

Comment: you can replace you delete operation with `echo` or add `-i` to `rm`

Comment: but the *.sh file I'm reading contains thousands of lines of code. I don't want to replace the functions one by one.

Comment: each function are different ?? A simple sed seems easy, or any editor can do the replace. for example change `rm` to `RM` and define RM to `rm` or `echo` at the top of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of 'dry run' in bash actually is not possible. What would be the ouptput e.g in cases like the following:

```
if some_command; then
  variable=output_1
else
  variable=output_2
fi
```

In order to determine the script flow you have to execute the **some_command** which may require running some command and getting its output. This will modify your system (it will depend on the command). Thus, there's no 'safe' way to do what you need without executing the bash script.

In order to test your script will have to simulate the commands which could modify your system (by adding an **echo** at the beginning e.g). This way you can run the script and see the values for your variables.